# store result of for loop in a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R called "temptabelle" from where I need to pick 156 temperatures. I need them for calculation, therefore I want to store the temperatures in a vector.
I wrote a for-loop which picks the certain temperatures:

> `result<-numeric(156)`
>
> `for (i in seq(0,120389,768))`
>
> `result[i] <-  (temptabelle[(i+1349),3])`

this is the output from R:

> `[1] "1.78416442871094"`

It is the last temperature of the 156 temperatures. My goal is to get vector, which contains all 156 temperatures.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is not reproducible so it's hard to tell what's going on. What is `length(result)` or `length(res)`? Do you want to store it in `result` or `res`?

Comment: oh sorry I mean result[i]. When I use print(temptabelle[(i+1349),3] it prints all 156 temperatures, but I want to store it in a vector.

Comment: You don't need a loop. R is vectorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why a loop? Shouldn't `temptabelle[seq(0,120389,768)+1349,3]` be enough?

Comment: My thinking was too complicated! :D It works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to fix `result`'s index variable:

```
result<-numeric(156)
idx <- seq(0,120389,768)
for (i in 1:156)
  res[i] <- (temptabelle[(idx[i]+1349),3])
```

But it's hard to tell as you didn't provide a reproducible example, as @BlueMagister already wrote.